# Error inflating class fragment in google maps

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 5 tabs, and the third tab is a google map. It loads on the emulator at the beginning. When I click on the map tab, it displays "Google Services are not available." Then I click on a different tab. Now, I click on the map again, it forces stops and the logcat says error inflating fragment. The error pointed to this method in my main activity.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Also there is a line that I dont know what it means

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #15: 
Duplicate id 0x7f05000b, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

I checked **R.java** but there is only one object with that Id. which is my map.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Emulator cannot run Google Map service.
- If you are testing on device, please update google service. Older version of Google service don't support Google map Api v2.
- SupportMapFragment only run in FragmentActivity.